# How to make a dialog with FormBorderStyle = FixedSingle in a WiX custom action?

Tags: .net, winforms, wix, windows-installer, formborderstyle

When I use `FormBorderStyle = FixedSingle` on a winform it shows a thin border like this:

[image]

But the same form when invoked during a Setup Custom Action written in WiX the border is of a resizable window

[image]

Why is this FormBorderStyle property being ignored? How to make it work on WiX?

Comment: I would strongly recommend you NOT to spawn UI from inside the custom action! It has a number of negative effects. Instead, design a dialog using the Windows Installer capabilities (yes, quite limited) and incorporate it into the UI sequence the Windows Installer way.

Comment: @YanSklyarenko I would follow your recommendation if I knew how to alter the order of the WiX dialogs from the custom action.

Comment: The order of the dialogs is not altered from inside the custom action. Instead, it is defined in the `UI` element. If you take WiX UIExtention sources as an example, take a look at WixUI_Advanced.wxs, for instance. There's a number of `Publish` elements, which define the sequence and extra actions based on various conditions